# how to pass environment varibles to docker-compose run from rancher compose command

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, bamboo, rancher

I have the following docker file created for the spring boot application

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV environment default
ADD target/docker-sample-example.jar docker-sample-example.jar
EXPOSE 8087
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=${environment}","docker- 
sample-example.jar"]
```

i want to set the value "environment" in the docker-compose , or pass the value through bamboo environment variable to make it available during run time to pick the proper profile while  deploying into rancher .

I have tried the following edit in docker-compose

```
version: "2"
services:
svc-get-interactions:
image: myaccount.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/app:latest
environment:
- environment = dev
ports:
- 9898:8082/tcp
labels:
  io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
```

but the variable was not picked while running the command "rancher compose up"

am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

> environment:
>
> > environment: "dev"

or

> environment:
>
> > - environment='dev'

On the docker-compose.yml file. Both work for me.